# is it possible to crack vpn traffic knowing password?

Tags: vpn

I want to know if it is secure to use a public fre vpn who use a public singe user and password for all users.
This vpn uses simply pptp.
Is it visible that traffic ?

Comment: You gain no security by using a VPN that is free and public.  It would be no different then connecting to a Free wireless access point which uses encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Technically no, the username and password is simply for authentication. Encryption is setup after authentication has succeeded.

Regardless if the VPN traffic can be "cracked", there's nothing stopping the VPN provider from reading all the unencrypted traffic after it goes through their server. With it being free and using only 1 shared account, I wouldn't exactly trust the provider for sensitive work